# Node.js get file name of the module from inside the module?

Tags: javascript, node.js

How to get the name of the Node.js module from inside the module itself during loading?

```
//mymodule.js
console.log(GET_MODULE_FULL_PATH_NAME())

//prog.js

require('/full/path/module')
   OR
require('./module')
   OR
require('module.js')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `__filename`.  That will get you what you want.

http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_filename